# Read an image with OpenCV in C++ and display it in C#

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, bitmap

I have a `Mat` in C++ which is presents my image.
I did some operation on in with `OpenCV` and now want to send it to my C# project and use it as an `ImageSource`.
But when I want to call the converter in c#, to convert it to `ImageSource`, I face to this error on `bitmapObj.Save` :

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

my sample C++ source is:

```
Bitmap^ SomeClass::Test(System::String^ imgFileName)
{
   auto fileName = msclr::interop::marshal_as<string>(imgFileName);
   Mat img = imread(fileName);  
   auto bmp = gcnew Bitmap(img.cols, img.rows, img.step, Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb, (IntPtr)img.data);
   img.release();
   return bmp;
}
```

and my sample c# code is:

```
private void ImageTester(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var image = testClass.Test("test.png");
    bg.Source = ConvertToBitmapImageFromBitmap(image);          
}   

public static BitmapImage ConvertToBitmapImageFromBitmap(Bitmap btm)
{
    using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        btm.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        BitmapImage bImg = new BitmapImage();
        bImg.BeginInit();
        bImg.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
        bImg.EndInit();
        return bImg;
    }
}
```

Comment: add a check for img.empty() after the imread(). you always have to check, when loading resources.

Comment: @berak : In fact I even saved it on hard by `imwrite` to make sure everything is all right. But still get the error.

Comment: ok, sorry, did not read properly. - problem is , that your gcnew Bitmap does not copy the pixels. once you leave SomeClass::Test(), they are gone.

Comment: So... What should I do to have them?

Comment: and it's strange that I can see width and height of the image in C# until exactly before .Save instruction. What's the reason of this one?

Comment: The same reason and solution in this post:  
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31623351/2159536